# c# asp.net FTP Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, ftp, download

I get "System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported. at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet" when trying to download an item from an ftp(which  have access to).  The upload seems to work fine and is done similarly I'll post both functions below:

```
private void Download(string filePath, string fileName)
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        try
        {
            //filePath = <<The full path where the file is to be created. the>>, 
            //fileName = <<Name of the file to be createdNeed not name on FTP server. name name()>>
            Label1.Text = filePath + "/" + fileName;
            FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Create);
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new
            Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileName));
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            long cl = response.ContentLength;
            int bufferSize = 2048;
            int readCount;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            while (readCount > 0)
            {
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            ftpStream.Close();
            outputStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }




public void Upload(string filename)
    {
        FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(filename);
        string uri = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/" + fileInf.Name;
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP +"/" + fileInf.Name));
        // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
        // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
        // after a command is executed.
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        // Specify the command to be executed.
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        // Specify the data transfer type.
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
        reqFTP.ContentLength = fileInf.Length;
        // The buffer size is set to 2kb
        int buffLength = 2048;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
        int contentLen;
        // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
        FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();
        try
        {
            // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
            Stream strm = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();
            // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
            contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
            // Till Stream content ends
            while (contentLen != 0)
            {
                // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
            }
            // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
            strm.Close();
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error");
        }
    }
```

and these are the function calls

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FullServer = "ftp://" + ftpServerIP;
        Download(FullServer, LbxServer.SelectedValue);
    }

    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Upload(LbxLocal.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Thank you all for any help on this matter.

Comment: It's hard to be certain without knowing which line of code generates the exception, but it is possible to generate an exception from that class when allocating a new file stream. Please validate that `filePath + "/" + fileName` is a valid file name, that the `filePath` directory exists, and that your process has write permissions to the directory.

Comment: yes I forgot to mention that that line is throwing the exception, but when I put in a breakpoint it appears to be the right location and I have access through filezilla so I'm assuming I don't need to do anything extra. "ftp://servername/DownloadEmail.aspx" is what I get and the ip that it displays for (servername) is correct when I checked the server.

Comment: FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(filePath + "/" + fileName, FileMode.Create);

this is the full line that is breaking the code
filePath = "ftp://myservername"
fileName = DownloadEmail.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that `ftp://myservername` is an invalid scheme for a new `FileStream`. Note that your `FileStream` represents the local target, not the remote file.

If your intent is to download a remote file to your local system, `filePath` should refer to a folder on your local network (e.g., `C:\temp` or `\\somecomputer\share`, etc.)

Comment: thanks, I tried this before and din't realize I was getting a different error.  But this is the correct answer I just don't have access to the folders on my work comp :(